# Can a Passbook pass be relevant for multiple days?

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

I'm trying to use relevantDate to refine when the passes for my app are shown.

The relevantDate options I know about are: specify a start and end time on a single day, or specify a single time which seems to show the pass in the lock screen for about a four-hour window in either direction (!), at least for the "generic" pass type.

It seems like there ought to be a way to specify, e.g., for a coupon, that it should be shown on the lock screen when they're in the store for the next two weeks, at which point it should expire.  Is there?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's not currently a way to do this.

Relevance is a cooperative effort between you and the system.  Your pass gives a point in time (the relevant date) and/or a point in space (the relevant locations).  There's no API to provide a duration or a region.  The system decides what radius to use around that location and what window of time to use around the date.  There is some documentation for the relevant locations [in the Passbook guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53) but the time window is not documented.  In practice, the time window is on the order of 4-8 hours, depending on the pass style.

You should go on Apple's [bug report page](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and file an enhancement request, describing how it would add value to your coupons to be relevant for multiple days.

Comment: Thanks for this... obviously, not the answer I'd hoped for but it's good to have confirmation of my very rough experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite what you are looking for, you could send a push update to remove the locations after the promotion period ends.

If you have a promotion that is valid in a particular store, then you could use locations with `relevantText` appropriate for the promotion period E.g. *20% Off, Ends Jan 20*.  Once the promotion ends, you then send a push with no locations (or replace with a new offer).

The `relevantDate` key is not supported by the `coupon` or `storeCard` pass types and there is no way to specify a custom lock screen message for a time based alert, so personally I prefer to use location alerts whenever a location is known.  The exception would be when it makes sense to remind the user a few hours beforehand (E.g. for a dental appointment or scheduled personal training session).

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what we ended up doing.  (Unfortunately since there are no guarantees that pushes will arrive, there are no guarantees that the user will not be dogged by a pass on their lock screen in perpetuity when they are near a relevant location; however, they can always delete it...)